# Uint clamped array to data url

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, canvas, base64url

I want to get part of a canvas in the base 64 data url format which will be sent to my api
for this is I am using the ctx.getImageData() method which is returning a clamped uint 8 array
here is the code:

```
        const data = ctx.getImageData(mousex, mousey, mousex1, mousey1);
        const clamped = data.data
}
```

I have tried many btoa methods but the either return a broken array full of `A` or a broken array with a lot of /

Comment: Can you show the codes that you tried, please, and how they resulted in a "*broken array*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) for this purpose.

1. First extract the part of your source image. You don't need getImageData() for that. Instead create a second canvas with `part_canvas = document.createElement("canvas")`, this canvas doesnt have to be visible on the page.
2. Assign it its size .width and .height of the part you want to extract
3. `part_ctx = part_canvas.getContext("2d")` on the canvas
4. Then [`part_ctx.drawImage(source_image, part_x, part_x, part_width, parth_height, 0, 0, part_width, parth_height);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) This will take a rectangualr area of the source image and put it in the invisble canvas.
5. Finally you can do `part_canvas.toDataURL()` and you have the data URL

Didn't test. But I think this should work.